# Sidebar Javascript Can't find functions in the Library that created the Sidebar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sidebar attached to a Google Doc.  I'm using the sidebar to learn more about how Google Docs is structured.  I've been using a button click to help me to locate the Body Child Text on the Document itself. When working, this simply moves the Body Child Text into view in the Document and highlights it in yellow for one second.

This is the html and the javascript:

```
<input id="txtfind0" type="button" value="Click to Find Text" onClick="hlBodyChildText(0)" />
function hlBodyChildText(idx) 
{
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(llBodyChildText).highLightBodyChildText(idx);
}

function llBodyChildText(idx) 
{
    google.script.run.lowLightBodyChildText(idx);
}
```

This is the Google Apps Script:

```
function highLightBodyChildText(idx)
{
  var doc=DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var child=doc.getBody().getChild(idx);
  var position=doc.newPosition(child, 0);
  doc.setCursor(position);
  child.asText().editAsText().setBackgroundColor('#ffff00');
  return idx;
}
function lowLightBodyChildText(idx)
{
  Utilities.sleep(1000);
  DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().getChild(idx).asText().editAsText().setBackgroundColor('#ffffff');
}
```

This was working satisfactorily until I decided to put it all into a library so that I could easily attach it to any document.  However it seems that the google.script.run calls require that the functions have to be contained in the script editor of the document.  They don't seem to be able to find the functions in the Library.

I tried this approach:

```
function hlBodyChildText(idx) 
    {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(llBodyChildText).myDocUtilities.highLightBodyChildText(idx);
    }
```

But that just results in the error 'Can't find highLightBodyChildText(idx) of undefined.

So that's when I decided to copy those functions directly from my library into the Code.gs file and it worked immediately.

So the question is: **Is there a way to expose these functions to the google.script.run calls without having to copy all of these file into each document.**

Comment: I have a feeling the answer may involve addons

Comment: Oh wow.  I guess the answer is addon.  It's working as an addon.

Comment: I guess it's time to learn more about addons.